# How do I loop between two lists in a function?

Tags: python

```
def compareTriplets(a, b):
  ap = 0
  bp = 0
  for i in a,b:
    if a[i] > b[i]:
      ap = ap + 1
    elif b[i] > a[i]:
      bp = bp + 1
    elif a[i] == b[i]:
      ap = ap + 0
  return ap,bp

a = [5,3,2]
b = [5,1,9]

comparison = (compareTriplets(a,b))
print(comparison)
```

When I run it, it says that list indices must be integers or slices, not list, but they are lists.

Why this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using zip in python? It could loop through two lists in parallel.

```
for u, v in zip(list1, list2):
   if u>v:
      ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using `zip()`, assuming lists A and B will always be of the same length, you could try the following (if you need to use the indices specifically):

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    if A[i] > B[i]:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to compare two triplets, and the result should tell you about the comparison of each element in one triplet with the corresponding element in the other triplet. Here's how I would do it:

```
def compare_triplets(a, b):
    r = []
    for i in [0,1,2]:
        if a[i] > b[i]:
            r.append(1)
        elif a[i] < b[i]:
            r.append(-1)
        else:
            r.append(0)

    return r

r = compare_triplets((1,2,3), (3,2,1))
print(r)
```